# Compressing multiple files in HandBrake not working as expected

Tags: handbrake

I recently started using HandBrake thanks to @gronostaj, who told me what settings to use. I then asked whether it’s possible to convert multiple files, either simultaneously or consecutively without having to manually select them each time.

This is what he told me:

> “Here's how to convert multiple files at once: click Tools menu > Options and then Output Files in the left pane. Make sure that Automatically name output files is enabled and change Default Path to some folder. Then click Close at the bottom. Before clicking Start click the little arrow next to Add To Queue and click Add All, then Start.”

Seems easy enough, but then here’s what happened: I put in a path to a folder where I want my shrunken files to land, and closed the window. I hit “Source” to choose my source file and selected the folder. But when I hit “Add to Queue” and selected all, it only put in two files and gave me this error message when I hit “Start”:

> “There are jobs on the queue with the same destination path. Please choose a different path for this job.”

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @gronostaj Do recall where you provided this advice? Might be helpful to add a link to it. I quickly checked this user’s questions and answers and I can’t seem to find the exact source of this advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Output Files tab under your preferences, besides specifying a default path, you need to enter in the "Format" box `{source}` which tells the program to name the output files the same name as your source file. There are other formatting options available as well, if you're interested. Hover your mouse over the "Format" field to see.

EDIT: I just tried to reproduce the problem on mine by removing `{source}` but I'm unable to reproduce the same problem. Instead, the program automatically generates a varying name to avoid conflict. Maybe you're on an older version? (Mine's already quite old at 0.10.2.7286) Anyhow, do comment if my suggested solution didn't work.

Comment: Thanx for the response. I just downloaded HandBrake, so I’m guessing it’s the latest version; it’s 0.10.3.0 – 64bit version, if that helps at all. In my “format” field was {source}-{title} – that was there by default, I didn’t put it there – which now makes me wonder if it’s using the minus sign to remove the title, thus making them all have the same destination.

Comment: When I removed the _-{title}_ and hit start, it started the process; this is a good sign, as before it would give me the aforementioned error message, but it takes so darn long for the files to be compressed I don’t know whether it will then move on to the next one once the first one is completed. But at least it seems to be moving in the right direction! LOL I’m going to let it go and check back in the morning; I’ll update then. Thanx again!

Comment: Well, if the queue adds and starts running, I haven't experienced any sudden problems after that. Hope you got it solved! Try tweaking the settings if it's going too slowly. You may have given it really tough jobs!

Comment: Did you manage to get your problem solved?

Comment: I did, yes! Thank you again for all of your help. :)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, no answers I found worked. Ended up resolving this myself.

In Preferences > Output Files, under File Format it said "{source}". I changed this to "{source} {title}" and now it works as expected.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

To select multiple files to add to the queue:

1. Click [Open Source]: Select the FOLDER that has the files. Then click [Open]. Files can only be added one at a time if you're browsing the files.  This scans the files, but doesn't add them to the queue.
2. In the File menu, select "Add Titles to Queue...".  Select the titles, and click [Add].